# How to assign a List<ClassB> to a setter which takes List<ClassA> and ClassB extends ClassA

Tags: java, generics

I have something like

```
public void setCustomHandler(final List<ClassA> customHandler) {
    this.customHandler = customHandler;
}
```

Now I create a classB and call `setCustomHandler(List<B>)`. Eclipse is telling me to create

```
setCustomHandler(final List<ClassB> customHandler){
}
```

How can I just assign

```
List<ClassB objects> to List<ClassA objects>?
```

Comment: Is ClassB subclass of Class A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

`List<ClassB>` is not a subtype of `List<ClassA>` (even if `ClassB` is a subtype of `ClassA`):

```
List<ClassA> handlerList;
List<ClassB> bHandlers = new ArrayList<ClassB>();

handlerList = bHandlers; // Type mismatch: cannot convert from
                         // List<ClassB> to List<ClassA>
```

---

If you have the control of the receiving class, you could perhaps let it accept `List<? extends ClassA>` instead:

```
List<? extends ClassA> handlerList;
List<ClassB> bHandlers = new ArrayList<ClassB>();

handlerList = bHandlers;  // Compiles fine.
```

Comment: he doesn't indicate a class hierarchy

Comment: Actually I didn't, but thanks for pointing it out. Updated the answer slightly ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
setCustomHandler(final List<? extends ClassA> customHandler){
   }
```

That was the short answer, the long answer is: depends waht you want to do in `setCustomHandler()`. If you want to get from the list, that that works, but if you want to put in the list, it wont work. The reason is: `List<? extends ClassA> customHandler` says that `customHandler` contains some subtype of ClassA, but you don't know which one, which prevents you to `add` (you do not know what is in the list). 
If you want to put in the list you have to do

```
setCustomHandler(final List<? super ClassA> customHandler){
   }
```

which says that `customHandler` contains some *supertype* of ClassA. This allows you to put ClassB, but does not allow *get*.

*Effective Java* from Bloch and *The Java Programming Language* from Arnold explain all these things in deatil.

Comment: But then, the OP can't pass a list of `List<ClassA>` to the method.

Comment: Why not? `ClassA` is a subtype of `ClassA`, no?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That's what generics is there to *prevent*.

Comment: There are solutions for this problem, and is the wildcard ? extends, because every classB object is also a classA object.

Comment: Fair enough - I didn't notice the title that classb extends classa

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `List<ClassA>` and the set the object of `ClassB`, as the reference variable will be of type `ClassA`, then u can call the method you need to call.

```
List<ClassA> list = new ArrayList<ClassA>();
ClassA object = new ClassB();
list.add(object);
setCustomerHandler(list);
```

This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If ClassA and ClassB have no relation then you can't. If they are in the same hierarchy structure (suppose both inherits from ClassC) put a parent class reference (ClassC).

For example:

```
public ClassC{}
public ClassA<T extends ClassC> extends ClassC{
public void setCustomHandler(final List<T> customHandler) {
    this.customHandler = customHandler;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember much java but I believe it is something like that :

Create a `List<ClassA>` and add all your ClassB items to it like this :

```
List<ClassA> myList = new List<ClassA>();
myList.addAll(myListOfOtherItems);
```

Now you can use myList to call your method since it's of type `List<ClassA>` but contains ClassB items that extends ClassA

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that while `ClassA` and `ClassB` have a specific relationship, `List<ClassA>` and `List<ClassB>` do not have one.

You cannot assign, instead you have to insert the elements in the first list to the second list one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You can use wildcard `?`,

```
void setCustomHandler(final List<?> customHandler)
```

But you will have to find out the parameterized type somehow.

Comment: That solution will prevent the method to use the objects inside the list, because a "get" will return "Object", and even worse... the caller would be able to call the method with every kind of list. This solution is awful.